# How to retrieve a multiple row array from a prepared statement

Tags: php, arrays

The function in this post RETURNS a great array of 1 row of the query. But the result delivers more than 1 row. I Googled a lot, but i didn`t find the answer for my question; How to retrieve an ARRAY for a SELECT statement triggered by a PREPARED statment?

Thanks in avance

/**********************************************************************************************************************************

```
3. Customer view ******************************************************************************************************************

***********************************************************************************************************************************/

function customer_view($user_name) {

  global $mysqli;

  $query_select = ("SELECT * FROM customers where user_name = ? ");
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_select);
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_name);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $count = $stmt->num_rows();

   $stmt->bind_result ($customer_number         ,
                       $user_name               , 
                       $customer_name               ,
                       $customer_legal_sort       ,
                       $customer_vat_applicable ,
                       $customer_payment_terms  ,
                       $customer_contactperson  ,
                       $customer_email          ,
                       $customer_telphone       ,
                       $customer_address_visit  ,
                       $customer_number_visit   ,
                       $customer_num_add_visit  ,
                       $customer_postal_visit   ,
                       $customer_city_visit     ,
                       $customer_country_visit  ,
                       $customer_visit_vs_post  ,
                       $customer_address_post     ,
                       $customer_number_post      ,
                       $customer_num_add_post       ,
                       $customer_postal_post    ,
                       $customer_city_post      ,
                       $customer_country_post   ); 


      $stmt->fetch();


      $customer_data = array ( 'customer_number'        =>$customer_number         ,
                               'user_name'              =>$user_name               , 
                               'customer_name'          =>$customer_name                 ,
                               'customer_legal_sort'    =>$customer_legal_sort       ,
                               'customer_vat_applicable'=>$customer_vat_applicable ,
                               'customer_payment_terms '=>$customer_payment_terms    ,
                               'customer_contactperson' =>$customer_contactperson  ,
                               'customer_email'         =>$customer_email          ,
                               'customer_telphone'      =>$customer_telphone         ,
                               'customer_address_visit' =>$customer_address_visit  ,
                               'customer_number_visit'  =>$customer_number_visit     ,
                               'customer_num_add_visit' =>$customer_num_add_visit    ,
                               'customer_postal_visit'  =>$customer_postal_visit   ,
                               'customer_city_visit'    =>$customer_city_visit     ,
                               'customer_country_visit' =>$customer_country_visit    ,
                               'customer_visit_vs_post' =>$customer_visit_vs_post    ,
                               'customer_address_post'  =>$customer_address_post     ,
                               'customer_number_post'   =>$customer_number_post    ,
                               'customer_num_add_post'  =>$customer_num_add_post     ,
                               'customer_postal_post'   =>$customer_postal_post    ,
                               'customer_city_post'     =>$customer_city_post      ,
                               'customer_country_post'  =>$customer_country_post   ); 


  return $customer_data; 

} //end of customer_view() function
```

Comment: That is because you only fetch 1 row. You have to loop through the other rows as well. Too tired to write any code so not an answer just a comment.

Comment: #David: Common, it`s Sunday evening (Amsterdam time). You must have  a little free time to help this starting PHP student a bit further. I Promise a digital beer will be your reward ;-)

Comment: In the above select statement, you're selecting a specific user_name. Are you sure you have multiple usernames being returned for that match? Furthemore, you would use `while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ //$row now contains each row returned from db }` instead of `$stmt->fetch();`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, many thanks for your helpfull answer! For your information, a user_name can have more customers. My questioan now; is $row now an array? I mean, how can I now save the results of the query into an array? I see I need a `While` but i still do`nt understand how to put the result into an assiciative or nemeruic array. Can you please help me a second time? Great thanks!

Comment: @:Krooy, it may have been evening where you are but it was late night here in Bangkok. I'm on holiday visiting my brother here :)

Comment: @David; Wow, Bangkok! (Or should I say sin-city :) Enjoy the pad-thai, cheap Chang beer and nice people. Have fun, and say hello to your brother from me.  Regards, Koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to iterate over the returned result set, simply do the following:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     $customer_data[] = array ( 'customer_number'        =>$customer_number         ,
                           'user_name'              =>$user_name               , 
                           'customer_name'          =>$customer_name                 ,
                           'customer_legal_sort'    =>$customer_legal_sort       ,
                           'customer_vat_applicable'=>$customer_vat_applicable ,
                           'customer_payment_terms '=>$customer_payment_terms    ,
                           'customer_contactperson' =>$customer_contactperson  ,
                           'customer_email'         =>$customer_email          ,
                           'customer_telphone'      =>$customer_telphone         ,
                           'customer_address_visit' =>$customer_address_visit  ,
                           'customer_number_visit'  =>$customer_number_visit     ,
                           'customer_num_add_visit' =>$customer_num_add_visit    ,
                           'customer_postal_visit'  =>$customer_postal_visit   ,
                           'customer_city_visit'    =>$customer_city_visit     ,
                           'customer_country_visit' =>$customer_country_visit    ,
                           'customer_visit_vs_post' =>$customer_visit_vs_post    ,
                           'customer_address_post'  =>$customer_address_post     ,
                           'customer_number_post'   =>$customer_number_post    ,
                           'customer_num_add_post'  =>$customer_num_add_post     ,
                           'customer_postal_post'   =>$customer_postal_post    ,
                           'customer_city_post'     =>$customer_city_post      ,
                           'customer_country_post'  =>$customer_country_post   ); 
}
```

Note that the `$customer_data[]` has been changed. We're appending an auto-incrementing index to the array. in this way - you will have an interatable array with values from each row.

Comment: This doesn`t work, because i work wit Prepared statements. This is the error I receive when using your suggestion: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in /mnt/webr/c3/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 333